# Type mismatch. Required: Result<List<DataItem>>! Found: Success

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, sealed-class

I am have implemented sealed classes if I get response correctly I will get Result.Success if the error Resuilt.Error

below my ViewModel where I have  implemented that logic

```
@HiltViewModel
class GiphyTaskViewModel
@Inject
constructor(private val giphyTaskRepository: GiphyTaskRepository):ViewModel()
{
    var giphyresponse=MutableLiveData<Result<List<DataItem>>>()


    fun getGifsFromText(apikey:String,text:String,limit:Int)= viewModelScope.launch {
    giphyTaskRepository.getGifsFromText(apikey,text,limit).let { response->
        if(response?.isSuccessful){
            var list=response.body()?.data
            giphyresponse.postValue(Success(list))
        }else{
            giphyresponse.postValue(Error(Exception(response.message())))

        }

    }
}

}
```

below my sealed class Result

```
sealed class Result<T>
data class Success(val data: Any) : Result<Any?>()
data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Any?>()
```

but when I run project I am getting following error

Type mismatch. Required: Result<List>! Found: Success

Answer (score 1):

> Type mismatch. Required: Result! Found: Success

That's exactly your problem. You've declared `LiveData` to emit `Result<List<DataItem>>`. `Success` is a `Result<Any?>`. It doesn't conform to the constraints you've set for `giphyresponse`.

To post `Success`, it should be of `Result<T>` or `Result<List<DataItem>>>`, depending on your hierarchy.

To post `Error`, it also must be of `Result<List<DataItem>>>` and it has to create an empty list - because the list is mandatory. Another approach would be to define giphyresponse as `MutableLiveData<Result<List<DataItem>?>>()` so `Error` can carry `null` data instead of dummy list.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Success` extends `Result<Any?>`, so it is not a subtype of `Result<List>`. You need to parameterize it:

```
data class Success<T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
```

Also, there is already a similar util in Kotlin stdlib, it is better optimized than your own. It is named... Result ;-) https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/

**Update**

One additional problem I didn't notice initially is that you named your class `Error` and there is already `Error` class in Java/Kotlin, so it might cause problems. The easiest is to rename it.

Note it isn't trivial to provide you a fully working example, but try this:

```
giphyTaskRepository.getGifsFromText(apikey,text,limit).let { response->
    if(response?.isSuccessful){
        var list=response.body()?.data ?: error("Don't know what to do here")
        giphyresponse.postValue(Success(list as List<DataItem>))
    }else{
        giphyresponse.postValue(Err(Exception(response.message())))
    }
}

sealed class Result<out T>
data class Success<T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
data class Err(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
```

As I said, I have no idea what is your expected behavior when `body()` is null, so I just thrown an error.

Also, I don't know what is the type of `body().data`, but I assumed it is just `Any`, so I casted it. It may be unnecessary.

Comment: but I am getting following exception Required:
List<DataItem>
Found:
List<DataItem>?

Comment: This is another problem: your `list` is nullable, so you sometimes have a list of items and sometimes not, but you marked your function as it always returns a list. What's your expected behavior if `body()` is null?

Comment: can you post your answer with fully with code

Comment: but I am getting this exception Type mismatch.
Required:
List<DataItem>
Found:
Result<List<DataItem>?>

Comment: In which line do you get it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142212/type-mismatch-inferred-type-is-resultlistdataitem-but-listdataitem-was-e I have posted here

Comment: I have already posted my question as separated post please check it when you have a time