# Type mismatch: inferred type is Result<List<DataItem>?> but List<DataItem> was expected

Tags: android, list, kotlin, mismatch

I have implemented Result.Success and Result.Error in my ViewModel class but I am getting following error  in my SecondActivity.kt C:\Users\Edgar\AndroidStudioProjects\GiphyAndroidApp\app\src\main\java\com\example\giphyandroidapp\ui\SecondActivity.kt: (52, 52): Type mismatch: inferred type is Result<List?> but List was expected

below my SecondActivity.kt

```
  package com.example.giphyandroidapp.ui
import com.example.giphyandroidapp.utils.Result
import com.example.giphyandroidapp.utils.Error
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.giphyandroidapp.utils.Constants
import com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.GiphyTaskViewModel
import com.example.giphyandroidapp.adapters.GiphyTaskAdapter

import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import com.example.giphyandroidapp.databinding.ActivitySecondBinding
import com.example.giphyandroidapp.utils.Success
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() ,View.OnClickListener {

    lateinit var binding: ActivitySecondBinding
    val viewModel: GiphyTaskViewModel by viewModels()

    var text: String = ""
    lateinit var myadapter: GiphyTaskAdapter


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivitySecondBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val intent = intent
        if (intent.hasExtra("text")) {
            // list= intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Parcelable>("response")!! as List<DataItem>
            text = intent.getStringExtra("text").toString()

            if (text != null) {
                bindData()
            }
        }

        binding.getresultbtn.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    private fun bindData() {

        viewModel.getGifsFromText(Constants.Api_Key, text, Constants.Limit)

        viewModel.giphyresponse.observe(this,
            { response ->


                when (response) {
                     is Success -> {
                        myadapter = GiphyTaskAdapter(this, response.data)
                    }
                     is  Error -> {

                    } // Handle error case
                }


                binding.imgsrecycler.apply {
                    adapter = myadapter
                    layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@SecondActivity, 2)
                    visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
                binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            })
        }




    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        var mytext: String = ""
        mytext = binding.txtword.text.toString()

        if (mytext.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "you must enter word", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {


            if (text.equals(mytext)) {
                val builder = android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                builder.setTitle("Winner")
                builder.setMessage("Excellent , you win \n Play game again ?!")
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes") { dialog, which ->
                    startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
                }
                builder.setNegativeButton("No") { dialog, which ->
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
                builder.create().show()

            } else {

                val builder = android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                builder.setTitle("Loser")
                builder.setMessage("fail , you lose \n Game over ! \n Play game again ?!")
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes") { dialog, which ->
                    startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
                }
                builder.setNegativeButton("No") { dialog, which ->
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
                builder.create().show()

            }

        }
    }
}
```

below GiphyAdapter.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import coil.load
import com.example.giphyandroidapp.databinding.ListItemBinding
import com.example.giphyandroidapp.model.gifsresponse.DataItem
import com.example.giphyandroidapp.model.gifsresponse.Images
import com.example.giphyandroidapp.utils.Result

class GiphyTaskAdapter(val context: Context,val list:List<DataItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<GiphyTaskAdapter.GiphyTaskViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): GiphyTaskAdapter.GiphyTaskViewHolder {
        return GiphyTaskViewHolder(ListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: GiphyTaskAdapter.GiphyTaskViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var item:DataItem = list.get(position)
        var imageitem: Images =item.images
        holder.binding.apply {
            img.load(imageitem.original.url){
                crossfade(true)
                crossfade(1000)
            }
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {mview->

        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount()=list.size

    inner class GiphyTaskViewHolder(val binding: ListItemBinding):
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
}
```

below my ViewModel class where I have implemented Result.Success and Result.Error logic

```
@HiltViewModel
class GiphyTaskViewModel
@Inject
constructor(private val giphyTaskRepository: GiphyTaskRepository):ViewModel()
{
    var giphyresponse = MutableLiveData<Result<List<DataItem>?>>()



    fun getGifsFromText(apikey:String,text:String,limit:Int)= viewModelScope.launch {
    giphyTaskRepository.getGifsFromText(apikey,text,limit).let { response->
        if(response?.isSuccessful){
            var list=response.body()?.data
            giphyresponse.postValue(Success(list))
        }else{
            Error(Exception(response.message()))

        }

    }
}

}
```

below Repository class

```
class GiphyTaskRepository
@Inject
constructor(private val giphyTaskApiService: GiphyTaskApiService)
{

    suspend fun getGifsFromText(apikey:String,text:String,limit:Int)=
        giphyTaskApiService.getGifsFromText(apikey,text,limit)
}
```

below my network interface

```
interface GiphyTaskApiService {

    @GET("gifs/search")
    suspend fun getGifsFromText(
        @Query("api_key") api_key:String,
        @Query("q") q:String ,
        @Query("limit") limit:Int
    ):Response<GiphyResponse>
}
```

below GiphyResponse.kt

```
@Parcelize
data class GiphyResponse(

    @field:SerializedName("pagination")
    val pagination: Pagination,

    @field:SerializedName("data")
    val data: List<DataItem>,

    @field:SerializedName("meta")
    val meta: Meta
) : Parcelable
```

below  Result class

```
sealed class Result<T>
data class Success<T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Any?>()
```

I want to know what I have to do in order to successfully implement result.success and result.error class and pass correct paremeter so that avoid mismatch error

I am getting following mismatch after implementing murat's answer

[image: mismatch error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GiphyTaskAdapter expects List, but in ViewModel you have Result<List?>.

```
class GiphyTaskAdapter(val context: Context,val list:List<DataItem>)
var giphyresponse = MutableLiveData<Result<List<DataItem>?>>()
```

So, for example, you can change a type in ViewModel.

```
var giphyresponse: MutableLiveData<List<DataItem>> = MutableLiveData()
...
val list: List<DataItem> = response.body()?.data ?: emptyList()
giphyresponse.postValue(list)
```

UPD:
sealed class can be handled as Marat wrote. Also, you should handle null type.

```
when(response) {
    is Success -> {
        val list: List<DataItem> = response.data ?: emptyList()
        myadapter = GiphyTaskAdapter(this, list)
        
        .......
    }
    is Error -> // Handle error case
}
```

Comment: if I will gonna change I cant implement result.success and result.error logic

Comment: your answer not correct please dont answer if you cant understand my problem

Comment: So, you can rephrase your problem and remove unnecessary information to be more understandable. If the problem in handling sealed classes, then Marat gave the correct answer how to this can be handled

Comment: already reproduce the marat answer not recognizing response.data

Comment: in this line I am getting error myadapter = GiphyTaskAdapter(this, response?.data) response.data   type mismatch.
Required:
List<DataItem>
Found:
List<DataItem>?

Comment: So you need non-nullable type and you put nullable type. Just handle null somehow. I.e. response.data?.let{ GiphyTaskAdapter(this, it) }

Comment: Incompatible types: Error and Result<List<DataItem>?>!

Comment: Why there is an Error type here? Did you put it in the "is Error" branch?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234264/discussion-between-jack-philips-and-runny).

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

You need to check your `response` if it is successful or not. Something like:

```
when(response) {
    is Success -> {
        myadapter = GiphyTaskAdapter(this, response.data)
        .......
    }
    is Error -> // Handle error case
}
```

Comment: can you help me to write SecondActivity.kt logic because I am getting error in viewModel.giphyresponse.observe(this, { response -

Comment: Did you import it? That is the code which you can put into SecondActivity

Comment: maybe I have to updated my secondactivity

Comment: Then you can try just `is Success ->` without `Result`

Comment: Where do you see `result.data`? Please, adapt the code as you need. I just showed you how to handle `Result` class in general

Comment: I am getting error here myadapter = GiphyTaskAdapter(this, response.data) respnse.data // data line giving red error

Comment: what is your suggestion

Comment: Type mismatch.
Required:
List<DataItem>
Found:
List<DataItem>?